# vista basada en funciones django

Tags: python, django, views

Estoy avanzando en el desarrollo de django con una aplicación, inicialmente con el uso de vistas basadas en funciones, mi idea es también manejar las vistas basadas en clases, y estoy con una aplicación que me permita recuperar un registro de una tabla a partir del ID de esa tabla, la vista es:

```
def recibo_edit(request, id_recibo):
    recibo = Recibo.objects.get(id=id_recibo)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ReciboForm(instance=recibo)
    else:
        form = ReciboForm(request.POST, instance=recibo)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('recibo:recibo_listar')
    return render(request, 'recibos/recibo_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Mientras que en el archivo urls.py de la aplicación recibo, tengo lo siguiente:

```
app_name ='recibos'

urlpatterns = {
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('nuevo/', recibo_view, name='recibo_nuevo'),
    path('listar/', recibo_list, name='recibo_listar'),
    path('editar/(?P<id_recibo>\d+)/$', recibo_edit, name='recibo_editar'),
}
```

Al ejecutar el servidor de django, y usar la ruta para recuperar un registro: el id = 365 que si existe en la base de datos, me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
The current path, recibos/editar/365/, didn't match any of these
```

Al parecer todo está bien, pero no logro identificar dónde está el error. Agradezco de antemano sus comentarios.

Muchas gracias!
Gustavo.

Comment: Puedes entrar a las otras urls: `nuevo`, `listar`?

Comment: Hola @eyllanesc, de hecho con las otras vistas, no tengo problema, ya que puedo dar de alta un nuevo recibo y tengo la lista de todo el contenido de la tabla. Estoy usando django 2.0

Answer (score 2):

El error es causado porque la función [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path) introducida en Django 2.0 no usa expresiones regulares, en tu caso debes usar:

```
path('editar/<int:id_recibo>/', recibo_edit, name='recibo_editar')
```

Si desea usar una expresión regular, puede usar [re_path()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path):

```
re_path('editar/(?P<id_recibo>\d+)/$', recibo_edit, name='recibo_editar')
```

Tambien la funcion `url()` todavía funciona y ahora es un alias para re_path, pero es probable que esté en desuso en el futuro.

```
url(r'editar/(?P<id_recibo>\d+)/$', recibo_edit, name='recibo_editar')
```

Nota: la aplicacion debio darte el siguiente warning:

```
WARNINGS: ?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern 'editar/(?P<id_recibo>\d+)/$' has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().
```

Te recomiendo revisar el siguiente [enlace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/) para que conozcas las novedades de django 2.0

Comment: Me ha funcionado! Te agradezco mucho el apoyo @eyllanesc, revisaré con cuidado los nuevos cambios en python 2.0, es una herramienta muy potente y claro, nos obliga a conocer los cambios para no batallar como fue mi caso!

Comment: @Gustux Si mi respuesta fue de ayuda no olvides marcarla como correcta aprentando el check que esta a la izquierda de mi pregunta :P